# XAMPP MySQL Access Denied ** ONLY if not connected to Internet **

Tags: mysql, xampp

My apologies in advance if this is a dup. Seems like it should be but I'm not able to find anyone else with the same question.

I'm using XAMPP - MySQL. Everything works fine *unless* I am not connected to the Internet.

If and ONLY if I am not connected to the Internet do I get the message:

Access denied for user 'jon'@'localhost' (using password:YES)

...where 'Jon' is my user name. There is no further information in the log.

Again - all I have to do to fix this is connect to the Internet - but I am not always able to do this and need to work even if there is no Internet.

Thanks - Jon

Answer (score 0):

I never figured out the cause, but the work-around was to delete the user account and re-add it. It seems odd because the problem only happened when no Internet connection. But it's working now.